# Do Gorilla websockets support concurrent read/writes for different connections?

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I am working on a Go application which accepts websocket connections from different client. I have used the Gorilla websocket library.
From the documentation page [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#:%7E:text=Connections%20support%20one%20concurrent%20reader%20and%20one%20concurrent%20writer),
It says, no concurrent read/writes are permitted.

But it does not clearly say that wether concurrency is not at all supported throughout all the connections **OR** it is not supported only for that specific client.

That means - I know you can not read and write to same connection concurrently. But **Concurrently read from one connection and write to another.**
Is it allowed?

Can anyone help me in understanding this basics. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation says](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket#hdr-Concurrency):

> Connections support one concurrent reader and one concurrent writer.

The documentation is saying that *each* connection can have at most one reader and one writer. To put this another way, the following operations are *not* allowed:

- Two or more concurrent readers on the same connection.
- Two or more concurrent writers on the same connection.

The concurrency restriction in the package allows for the following:

- The application can concurrently read and write the same connection (contrary to the assertion in the question).
- The application can read from multiple connections concurrently where each connection has one concurrent reader.
- The application can write to multiple connections concurrently where each connection has one concurrent writer.
- The application can concurrently read from one connection and write to another connection. One connection has a reader, the other connection has a writer.